# Implementation View vs Physical View in 4+1 architectural view model

Tags: uml, ooad

As I read about `4+1 architectural view model` from the following link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%2B1_architectural_view_model

What is the precise differences between Development view (`implementation view`) and `Physical view`??

PS:I do know that the first one is from programmer perspective and the second one from system engineer perespective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physical view is used for depicting how the software is deployed in data centers.  For example: if you built a web application, then, say you will deploy it on Amazon AWS cloud.  Then physical view will show how many servers are used, what is the role of their server, what software components are installed on it, etc.   Hence, you can say that this view is of more importance for your operations team (System engineers as indicated in that Wiki page)

Development view is for communicating among developers as to what is the software design.  This mostly deals with logical organization of your code - package, classes, etc.

Hope it clarifies.